# Texlive Xetex Ubuntu font installation

Tags: fonts, xetex, installing-fonts

I am pretty new to Latex, basically never used it.
I have to create a Jenkins Server to compile uploaded Latex reports.
I tried that on my own server with Ubuntu 20.4

The compilation worked fine but it could not find the fonts used in the .tex files. That is because it is a company font, that only employees get.
I found a zip containing all the .ttf files needed and after a bit of trial and error I managed to compile without any problems by extracting the .ttf files in my ~/.fonts folder.

I tried that again on a company server with Ubuntu LTS 22.4, setup everything the same, copied the fonts in the same folder but this time it doesnt work. I cannot really explain why, did I just have luck on the first try?

Error Messages:

```
! I can't find file <fontname>'.
<*> ... ; nonstopmode; input <fontname>
```

```
kpathsea: Running mktextfm <fontname>
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/mktexnam: Could not map source abbreviation T for <fontname>.
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/mktexnam: Need to update /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/map/fontname/special.map?
mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; ; nonstopmode; input <fontname>
```

I tried googling those errors but most answers are that  `\usepackage{fontspec}` is required in the .tex file. I couldnt find it in the given files but why would it compile on the other server?

Do you have any ideas what it could be? The .tex file did not change at all. Also it is not possibly to change anything in the .tex file because other people upload their files to check if the compilation is successful.

Let me know if you need any more information!

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is this is the error you get from compiling `(xe/lua)tex file` through the terminal or from something more convoluted?  If not, what do you get when compiling  `(xe/lua)tex file` through the terminal?

Comment: note if you use lualatex  you can use `.ttf` fonts directly, if you use pdflatex you can not. As you have not shown how you are using the font from ...tex it's hard to guess what you need

Comment: Can you use the newly-installed fonts in an ordinary text editor or word processor? If not, then you may need to run `fc-cache` or whatever your system uses to update its font cache.

Comment: @rallg Tried taht, did not work for me

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I thought that is also the case for xelatex. My call is `xelatex -interaction=batchmode <file.tex>`  I tried the same with lualatex, but the same error occured, font was not found. I also checked filenames, the fontname that lualatex cannot find is definitly in my ~/.fonts folder

Comment: @DaiBowen exactly the same errors in terminal. Jenkins only provides me with the terminal output as far as I know

Comment: I copied my .ttf files to `/usr/share/fonts/truetype` now Latex finds it. That is not the right way but are there any concerns with the solution except, that it is hard for anyone else to know where the fonts are?